# get element by parent() and next()

Tags: angularjs

I want to get text of element. I have written the code:

```
$scope.check = function ($event) {
                    var el = $event.target;
                    alert(angular.element(el).parent().next().find("span").text());
                }
```

the button that call this function is:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" onclick="EditMode(this,2)" ng-click="check($event)" style="display: none;"><em class="fa fa-save"></em></a>
```

sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't, do you have idea what's the problem and why it's not working always?

Thank you very much

Comment: you are getting different elements because of bubbling.

Comment: @DanielA.White Im get or right element or empty element, possible to solve it?

Comment: I’m not sure what you are hoping to accomplish. This goes against the way to do things in AngularJS

Comment: I try to get the next column text in table using buttom click. @DanielA.White

Comment: You can pass it to EditMode

Comment: how? Im get the content of table using $http get and repeat. I know how to do that in native js but I want to do that using angular to get the binding... @DanielA.White

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to access the DOM from your controller. That's why you're running into problems.

Comment: Should be marked as "bad practise".

Comment: Please post the relevant HTML code. There is no span in your question